# Change the symbol of specific data points in line plot, base R

Tags: r, graph, plot

I want to change the symbol of particular data points on a line graph in base R.

Here is an example of my plot:

```
month<-c("2010-08-01", "2010-09-01", "2010-10-01", "2010-12-01", "2011-01-01", "2011-02-01",
     "2011-03-01", "2011-04-01", "2011-05-01", "2011-06-01", "2011-07-01", "2011-09-01",
     "2011-11-01", "2012-01-01", "2012-02-01", "2012-03-01", "2012-05-01", "2012-07-01",
     "2012-08-01")
prevalence<-c(10,7.5,5.2,3.5,6.4,2.7,5.8,13.2,4.3,4.7,6.4,4.4,5.2,3.3,1.0,3.1,9.9,33.3,1.0)
df<-data.frame(month, prevalence)
df$month<-as.Date(df$month)
plot(df$month, df$prevalence,lwd = 1.8, ylim=c(0,40),pch=16, bty='n', 
 ylab="Prevalence (%)", xlab="Month",col='black',cex=1,cex.lab=1.0,cex.axis=1.0)
len = .07
axis(side = 1, at = df$month, labels=F, tck=-0.015)
axis(side=2, at=c(0,10,20,30,40,50), labels=c("", "", "", "", "", ""), tck=-0.015)
lines(df$month, df$prevalence, col='black', lwd=1.8)
```

The graph produced:[image]

The y-value for the second last point is much higher than the others, and I would like to change the point to an open circle to indicate that there were only 3 samples for this data point. As I have a several of these line graphs to overlay in the one plot, it would look to messy to try to indicate this another way like manually overlaying a symbol on the graph.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can specify a separate symbol for every data point. Just provide an array instead of a single value for the pch-option of plot

```
symbol <- rep(16,nrow(df))
symbol[df$prevalence >30] <- 21
plot(df$month, df$prevalence,lwd = 1.8, ylim=c(0,40),pch=symbol, bty='n', 
 ylab="Prevalence (%)", xlab="Month",col='black',cex=1,cex.lab=1.0,cex.axis=1.0)
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Do you know how I can achieve that according to the record number, rather than the value? When I try: `symbol[df[1,]] <- 21`  I get: Error in symbol[nyc[1, ]] <- 24 : invalid subscript type 'list'

Comment: Suppose you want to change the first value, just use `symbol[1] <- 21`.