# Change the last point's shape for each factor in R

Tags: r, ggplot2, plot

I am plotting the cumulative frequency for the reproductive output of 21 animals in ggplot, with the last point representing the lifetime reproductive output at death. I want the last point displayed as a star, but I am having difficulty partitioning the data.

I found this answer: [Change the symbol of specific data points in line plot, base R](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26504595/change-the-symbol-of-specific-data-points-in-line-plot-base-r)

The solution here requires a specific value for identifying the value of interest, whereas a need the last entry for each factor/id.

My data looks like this:

```
     Age Cum_Output       ID
1     3         71       1
2     9         68       2
3    10        179       2
4    11        209       2
5     1         17       3
6     2         89       3
7     6        121       3
8     7        241       3
9     8        602       3
10   10        306       3
```

My code is as follows:

```
symbol <- rep(10, nrow(s3))
symbol[s3$ID[s3$Cum_Output] == last(s3$ID[s3$Cum_Output])] <- 17

ggplot(s3, aes(Age, Cum_Output)) + geom_point(shape = symbol) + 
  geom_line(aes(color = factor(ID))) + theme_bw() + xlab("Age") +
  ylab("Cumulative Reproductive Output")
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can create a logical variable to mark the highest `Age` for each `ID`. I do this on the fly below. First, we group by `ID`, then for each unique `ID` we create a logical variable, `last.value`, that is `TRUE` for the highest `Age` (`max(Age)`) and `FALSE` otherwise. In your sample data, it looks like the values of `Cum_Output` for `ID=3` are not cumulative, but I've used the data as is in the code below.

```
library(tidyverse)

s3 %>% 
  group_by(ID) %>% 
  mutate(last.value = Age == max(Age)) %>% 
  ggplot(aes(Age, Cum_Output, color = factor(ID))) + 
    geom_line() + 
    geom_point(aes(shape=last.value, size=last.value)) + 
    theme_bw() + 
    labs(x="Age", y="Cumulative Reproductive Output", colour="ID") +
    scale_shape_manual(values=c(16, 8)) +
    scale_size_manual(values=c(2,4)) +
    guides(shape=FALSE, size=FALSE)
```

[image]